# Custom log filtering of parameters in rails 3 with config.filter_parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, conditional-statements

I'm filtering some fields in my Rails 3.1 app's config/application.rb file as usual with:

config.filter_parameters += [:field]

However, I have a json model where this field appears twice, in two different contexts (in the context of different objects inside the same json), and I'd like to filter only one of them. Is there a way to do this with filter_parameters + lambda? I believe not because the elements/json is flatten before passing it to the filter_params lambda, and this way, the notion of the context of each field is lost.

In case of not possible, is there a way to deactivate the default loggin per request and only log what is explicit (using logger.info, logger.warn, etc inside controllers/actions)

Thank you.